# Upon clicking one checkbox, all are being selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I am making a form with html pdo and has angular js for validation but the section where i need checkbox upon click one box rest of the checkboxs are also getteng check

my form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="declaration" id="declaration" ng-model="formData.decl"  /> 1 data<br/>
     
<input type="checkbox" name="declaration" id="declaration" ng-model="formData.decl" /> 2 data<br/>
```

here is the insert.php

```
///////////////////////
if(empty($form_data->decl))
{
 $error[] = 'Choosing declaration is required';
}
else
{
 $declaration = $form_data->decl;
}

$data = array(
 ':declaration' => $declaration
);

if(empty($error))
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl 
 (declaration) VALUES 
 (:declaration)
 ";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
 if($stmt->execute($data))
 {
  $message = 'Data Added';
 }
}
else
{
 $validation_error = implode(", ", $error);
}

$output = array(
 'error'  => $validation_error,
 'message' => $message
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

and here is the complete angular js

```
var app = angular.module('dynamicApp', []);
app.controller('dynamicController', function($scope, $http){

 $scope.success = false;
 $scope.error = false;
 
 $scope.rows = [{name: 'travel_details[]', name: 'remove'}];
 $scope.addRow = function(){
  var id = $scope.rows.length + 1;
  $scope.rows.push({'id':'dynamic'+id});
 };

 $scope.removeRow = function(row){
  var index = $scope.rows.indexOf(row);
  $scope.rows.splice(index, 1);
 };

 $scope.formData = {};

 $scope.submitForm = function(){
  $http({
   method:"POST",
   url:"insert.php",
   data:$scope.formData
  }).success(function(data){
   if(data.error != '')
   {
    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.error = true;
    $scope.errorMessage = data.error;
   }
   else
   {
    $scope.success = true;
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.successMessage = data.message;
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.rows = [{holder_name: 'travel_details[]', holder_name: 'remove'}];
    $scope.fetchData();
   }
  });
 };

});
```

I see the portion ng-model="formData.decl"  in the checkbox area is causing this issue. if I remove this then only single checkbox gets clicked but then form validation would not work.

Can someone help me out with this issue?

Thanks alot

Comment: please remove the angular tag as your question is about angularjs.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? How is PHP related to this question - does setting these checkboxes involve any server action?

Answer (score 0):

Both checkboxes are getting checked, because they're bound to the same model:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="declaration" id="declaration" ng-model="formData.decl"  /> 1 data<br/>
     
<input type="checkbox" name="declaration" id="declaration" ng-model="formData.decl" /> 2 data<br/>
```

You have to bind each input to a dedicated model field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="declaration1" id="declaration1" ng-model="formData.decl_1"  /> 1 data<br/>
     
<input type="checkbox" name="declaration2" id="declaration2" ng-model="formData.decl_2" /> 2 data<br/>
```

Please notice the property to which each of the inputs is being bound to (formData.decl_1, formData.decl_2). Additionally, I believe it's not W3C compliant to assign same ID to two elements on a DOM.